# Линия FASM Ассемблер в окне

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

В ассемблере совсем новичок, хочу разобрать как создать окно и поместить туда линию. Нашел алгоритм построения линии:

```
mov dl,10
mov ah,02h
int 21h
mov dl,13
mov ah,02h
int 21h
```

Пытаюсь подставить в код:

```
include 'win32ax.inc'

.code

  start:
        mov dl,10
        mov ah,02h
        int 21h
        mov dl,13
        mov ah,02h
        int 21h
        invoke  ExitProcess,0

.end start
```

Я так понимаю не хватает `invoke createwindowex` как правильно прописать?

Comment: int 21h - это сервисное прерывание DOS. В коде сделанном для windows оно работать не будет. Если делаете выполнимый файл windows то для всех операций используйте winapi

Comment: И то что вы нашли - это вывод на страндартный вывод символов с кодами 10 и 13, т.е. переход в начало следующей строки в текстовом режиме. Никакого отношения к каким либо "линиям" это не имеет, если вы конечно под "линией" понимаете некий набор точек, находящихся на одной прямой и выводимый в графическом режиме

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что вы нашли - это примеры для dos, под windows они совершенно не применимы (к тому же вообще не относится к рисованию чего-либо).

Для рисования в окне сначала нужно создать это окно. Чтобы увидеть как это делается - идем в папку примеров fasm, смотрим шаблон оконного приложения (у меня это `c:\fasm\EXAMPLES\TEMPLATE\TEMPLATE.ASM`). Пример на 75 строк - это все только для создания окна и базовой обработки сообщений окна (хотя за счет использования `win32wx.inc` вместо `win32w.inc` можно было избавиться от явного создания секции импортов). Т.е. просто вызовом какой-нибудь одной функции дело не закончится. К слову, на С/С++ просто создание окна с использованием WinAPI займет примерно столько же строк.

Тут возможно стоит остановиться и задуматься, действительно ли вы хотите рисовать средствами WinAPI, еще и на ассемблере?

Код примера (без рисования) ниже:

```
; Template for program using standard Win32 headers

format PE GUI 4.0
entry start

include 'win32w.inc'

section '.text' code readable executable

  start:

    invoke  GetModuleHandle,0
    mov [wc.hInstance],eax
    invoke  LoadIcon,0,IDI_APPLICATION
    mov [wc.hIcon],eax
    invoke  LoadCursor,0,IDC_ARROW
    mov [wc.hCursor],eax
    invoke CreateSolidBrush, 0x00FF00
    mov [wc.hbrBackground], eax
    invoke  RegisterClass,wc
    test    eax,eax
    jz  error

    invoke  CreateWindowEx,0,_class,_title,WS_VISIBLE+WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,128,128,256,192,NULL,NULL,[wc.hInstance],NULL
    test    eax,eax
    jz  error
    ; invoke ShowWindow,eax,SW_SHOWNORMAL
  msg_loop:
    invoke  GetMessage,msg,NULL,0,0
    cmp eax,1
    jb  end_loop
    jne msg_loop
    invoke  TranslateMessage,msg
    invoke  DispatchMessage,msg
    jmp msg_loop

  error:
    invoke  MessageBox,NULL,_error,NULL,MB_ICONERROR+MB_OK

  end_loop:
    invoke  ExitProcess,[msg.wParam]

proc WindowProc uses ebx esi edi, hwnd,wmsg,wparam,lparam
    cmp [wmsg],WM_DESTROY
    je  .wmdestroy
  .defwndproc:
    invoke  DefWindowProc,[hwnd],[wmsg],[wparam],[lparam]
    jmp .finish
  .wmdestroy:
    invoke  PostQuitMessage,0
    xor eax,eax
  .finish:
    ret
endp

section '.data' data readable writeable

  _class TCHAR 'FASMWIN32',0
  _title TCHAR 'Win32 program template',0
  _error TCHAR 'Startup failed.',0

  wc WNDCLASS 0,WindowProc,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,COLOR_BACKGROUND,NULL,_class

  msg MSG

section '.idata' import data readable writeable

  library kernel32,'KERNEL32.DLL',\
      user32,'USER32.DLL',\
      gdi32,'GDI32.DLL'

  include 'api\kernel32.inc'
  include 'api\user32.inc'
  include 'api\gdi32.inc'
```

Дальше, для рисования линии вам нужны функции `MoveToEx` и `LineTo`, и воткнуть их вызов нужно не где-попало, а конкретно внутри процедуры обработки сообщений окна (в примере выше - `WindowProc`).

Просто чтобы рисовать линию при каждой перерисовке окна, нужно добавить обработку сообщения `WM_PAINT` в `WindowProc`:

```
proc WindowProc uses ebx esi edi, hwnd,wmsg,wparam,lparam
    cmp [wmsg], WM_DESTROY
    je  .wmdestroy
    cmp [wmsg], WM_PAINT
    je .wmpaint

.defwndproc:
    invoke  DefWindowProc,[hwnd],[wmsg],[wparam],[lparam]
    jmp .finish

.wmdestroy:
    invoke  PostQuitMessage,0
    xor eax,eax
    jmp .finish

.wmpaint:
    invoke BeginPaint, [hwnd], paintstruct ; получаем контекст окна
    mov [hdc], eax  ; сохраняем контекст окна в переменную
    invoke MoveToEx, [hdc], 10, 15, 0  ; 10, 15 - начальные координаты
    invoke LineTo, [hdc], 200, 100  ; 200, 100 - конечные координаты
    invoke EndPaint, [hwnd], paintstruct  ; освобождаем контекст окна

.finish:
    ret
endp
```

Полный код с рисованием:

```
format PE GUI 4.0

include 'win32wx.inc'

.data

_class TCHAR 'FASMWIN32',0
_title TCHAR 'Win32 program template',0
_error TCHAR 'Startup failed.',0

wc WNDCLASS 0,WindowProc,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,COLOR_BACKGROUND,NULL,_class

msg MSG

hdc dd ?
paintstruct PAINTSTRUCT

.code

start:
    invoke  GetModuleHandle,0
    mov [wc.hInstance],eax
    invoke  LoadIcon,0,IDI_APPLICATION
    mov [wc.hIcon],eax
    invoke  LoadCursor,0,IDC_ARROW
    mov [wc.hCursor],eax
    invoke CreateSolidBrush, 0xFFFFFF  ; белый фон
    mov [wc.hbrBackground], eax
    invoke  RegisterClass,wc
    test    eax,eax
    jz  error

    invoke  CreateWindowEx,0,_class,_title,WS_VISIBLE+WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,128,128,256,192,NULL,NULL,[wc.hInstance],NULL
    test    eax,eax
    jz  error
    ; invoke ShowWindow,eax,SW_SHOWNORMAL
msg_loop:
    invoke  GetMessage,msg,NULL,0,0
    cmp eax,1
    jb  end_loop
    jne msg_loop
    invoke  TranslateMessage,msg
    invoke  DispatchMessage,msg
    jmp msg_loop

error:
    invoke  MessageBox,NULL,_error,NULL,MB_ICONERROR+MB_OK

end_loop:
    invoke  ExitProcess,[msg.wParam]

proc WindowProc uses ebx esi edi, hwnd,wmsg,wparam,lparam
    cmp [wmsg], WM_DESTROY
    je  .wmdestroy
    cmp [wmsg], WM_PAINT
    je .wmpaint

.defwndproc:
    invoke  DefWindowProc,[hwnd],[wmsg],[wparam],[lparam]
    jmp .finish

.wmdestroy:
    invoke  PostQuitMessage,0
    xor eax,eax
    jmp .finish

.wmpaint:
    invoke BeginPaint, [hwnd], paintstruct ; получаем контекст окна
    mov [hdc], eax  ; сохраняем контекст окна в переменную
    invoke MoveToEx, [hdc], 10, 15, 0  ; 10, 15 - начальные координаты
    invoke LineTo, [hdc], 200, 100  ; 200, 100 - конечные координаты
    invoke EndPaint, [hwnd], paintstruct  ; освобождаем контекст окна

.finish:
    ret
endp

.end start
```

[image: Скриншот]